# How big is my pizza, if I know its slices' sizes?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

I bought a box of frozen pizza: eight slices, baked and then frozen, stacked in a box. The packaging assured me that I was holding an 18-inch[-diameter] pizza. That got me thinking: how do I know they're not lying?

Assume (though this may not be true of the pizza) that we have a circle<sup>[1]</sup> $S=\partial D$ centered at a point $O$ and four chords (closed line segments properly embedded in $D$) that intersect in a single point $C$. (Possibly $C=O$.) You may assume also (because this seems reasonable for pizza) that the angles made between adjacent chords (in the cyclic order around $C$) is between $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ and that the distance between $C$ and $O$ is less than the distance between $C$ and $S$.

Is it possible to use the lengths of the segments from $C$ to $S$ and the angles between adjacent segments to find the diameter of $D$? (If not, then would it be possible if my "you may assume also" assumptions were tightened a little?) If so, how?

(Of course, it's possible to find the diameter by measuring the arclengths of the curved parts of the slices of pizza, adding them up, and dividing by $\pi$. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it from the sidelengths and tip-of-the-slice angles of the pizza slices.)

---

<sup>[1] A geometric circle, meaning the locus of points a certain distance from $O$, not just a topological circle.</sup>

Comment: Would it be a legitimate move to measure the angle of the vertex of a slice of pizza by laying one side of the slice horizontally, and then measuring the projection of the other edge onto the horizontal axis and taking that to be the inner product? Then one could calculate the cosine of the angle and by extension, the angle. Does that violate the spirit of the question?

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean to take the projection alone as the inner product. It must be multiplied by the length of the horizontal edge as well.

Comment: Don't you think it might be easier handled by measuring the chord at the arc end of the slice - getting all the three sides of the triangle formed by the sides of the slice and its chord.

Comment: @TylerLevasseur, I was assuming the central angle is known.

Comment: @tpb261, interesting. I was more interested in the slices' sidelengths, to be honest, but, if you can make your method work, go for it.

Comment: the whole point being " if you can make your method work".... trying to wrap my brain around this problem since almost 4 hours... with little progress :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let a *pizza triangle* be the convex envelope of the vertices of a pizza slice. The area of any pizza triangle is a bit smaller then the area of its pizza slice, but not so much (especially given the condition on the angles). It is easy to compute the area of a pizza triangle through the sine theorem, so a simple criterion is given by computing the sum of the areas of the pizza triangles and compare it with the area of a regular octagon inscribed in a circle with diameter $18$ inches.

Anyway, given two opposite pizza slices it is not difficult to compute the radius of the disk from which they have been cut, since two opposite pizza slices give a cyclic quadrilateral  for which it is not difficult to compute the side lengths and the area given $a,b,c,d,\theta$:

[image]

hence the circumradius is provided by [Parameshvara's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Parameshvara.27s_formula):

$$ R = \frac{1}{4\Delta}\sqrt{(l_1 l_3+l_2 l_4)(l_1 l_2 + l_3 l_4)(l_1 l_4+l_2 l_3)} $$
where $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$ are the side lengths of the cyclic quadrilateral depicted above: they can be computed through the cosine theorem. Also notice that [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem) gives: $$l_1 l_3+l_2 l_4=(a+c)(b+d).$$

Another possible approach is the following. We have:
$$\text{pow}_\Gamma(C) = ac = bd = R^2-OC^2, $$
so we just need to find $OC^2$. If we take $M$ and $N$ as the midpoints of the chords in the picture above, it is trivial that $OC$ is the diameter of the circumcircle of $CMN$, and we may compute the circumradius of $CMN$ through the sine theorem:
$$\frac{OC}{2}=\frac{MN}{2\sin\theta}$$
then the length of $MN$ through the cosine theorem, so that:
$$ OC^2 = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\left(\left(\frac{a-c}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b-d}{2}\right)^2-\frac{|a-c||b-d|}{2}\cos\theta\right) $$
and:

> $$ R^2 = ac+\frac{1}{4\sin^2\theta}\left[(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2-2|a-c||b-d|\cos\theta\right].$$

If you do not know which couples of slices are "antipodal", well, they are not difficult to recognize: antipodal slices must have the same angle $\theta$ and fulfill $ac=bd$ (the intersecting chord theorem).